# How do I parse CSV content inside a SOAP Envelope using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, csv, soap

I have a SOAP Envelope:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">
      +++++REC START+++++
      1,Mr Egg Sample,
      +++++REC END+++++
      +++++REC START+++++
      2,Mr Other Egg Sample,
      4,Mr A N Other Egg Sample,
      +++++REC END+++++
    </text>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I must transform this into the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ex:ample xmlns:ex="http://example.org">
      1,Mr Egg Sample,
    </ex:ample>

    <ex:ample xmlns:ex="http://example.org">
      2,Mr Other Egg Sample,
      4,Mr A N Other Egg Sample,
    </ex:ample>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have looked at a lot of CSV-related XSLT examples such as [this](http://andrewjwelch.com/code/xslt/csv/csv-to-xml_v2.html) and [this](http://pragmaticintegrator.wordpress.com/2012/10/28/transforming-xml-to-csv-via-xslt/), but I don't have the expertise using XSLT to work out a solution from them. I wish I had the time to figure it out on my own, but I don't. Can anybody provide an XSLT solution to my problem?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you can use **xsl:analyze-string** to have regular expressions to match the text.

```
 <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\+\+\+\+\+REC START\+\+\+\+\+([\s\S]*?)\+\+\+\+\+REC END\+\+\+\+\+">
```

Note the use of the capturing group in the expression. Then, you can use the **regex-group** function to get the text you matched:

```
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <ex>
                <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />
            </ex>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*:text">
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\+\+\+\+\+REC START\+\+\+\+\+([\s\S]*?)\+\+\+\+\+REC END\+\+\+\+\+">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <ex>
                    <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)" />
                </ex>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

(Note, I haven't bothered created elements with namespaces here, but I am sure you can work that out)